# SQL SELECT QUERY

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sqlyog

i have 3 tables:

```
users:

uid int(11) - userid(primary key, auto_increment)
name varchar(255)
pass varchar(64)
created int(11)

projects:

pid int(11) .....
name varchar(150)
description varchar(255)
created int(11)

users_projects:

uid int(11) - user id
pid int(11) - product id
```

What is the query for: showing the projects(name and description) sorted by name for the user with a certain name?

This is what i've got so far:

```
SEECT name,description FROM projects ORDER BY name ASC
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle? Postgres?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT  a.*, b.*
FROM    users a
        INNER JOIN users_projects b
            ON a.uid = b.uid
        INNER JOIN projects c
            ON b.pid = c.pid
ORDER   BY a.Name ASC
```

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)

Comment: Those visual representations need some caveats attached to them.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you just need to join up the tables. Here `@Name` is a parameter containing the user's name you want project details for:

```
SELECT projects.Name,
       projects.Description
FROM   projects
       INNER JOIN users_projects
         ON projects.pid = users_projects.pid
       INNER JOIN Users
         ON users_projects.UId = Users.UId
WHERE  Users.Name = @Name
ORDER  BY projects.Name ASC
```